Making superLU on windows: fails on the first hurdle
When I try to make superLU on windows I take the following steps
I clone the superlu repo and cd into it.
I create a new dir build_win10 and cd into it
I run the command
cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icx -G "Unix Makefiles" ..

As per these instructions https://www.mystran.com/SuperLU/Compile_SuperLU.pdf This produces the error
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/compiler/latest/bin/icx.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/me/Devel/superlu/build_win10/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):make cmTC_e75fb/fast && The system cannot find the file specified
    Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: make cmTC_e75fb/fast &&

